# How to rerender entire single row in react-table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have a **react-table** component in my app and pass there next props:

```
<ReactTable
  data={this.props.words}
  columns={columns}
  getTrProps={changing_state_func}
/>
```

`changing_state_func` is a function that changes state of the component that wraps react-table. Specifically, this function fills an array that contains ids of the data objects for rows. So I'd like to highlight the rows with the data for those ids... Cannot figure it out how to do it with this particular datagrid. Maybe somebody has the experience working with react-table and example on this case.

Comment: ask on the repo for the ReactTable component? It's not standard React, that's a custom thing written by someone not associated with the official facebook React project

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yeah, I know. Just thought somebody here used it before and have an idea how it can be done

Comment: there is no `react-table` tag.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what actually you're trying to do, but here are my thoughts.

`getTrProps` is used to pass props to the table's rows.
So according [the module docs](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table), you can pass whatever you want.

The example shows how you can change the color of the rows, those meet specific condition:

```
// Any Tr element will be green if its (row.age > 20)
<ReactTable
  getTrProps={(state, rowInfo, column) => {
    return {
      style: {
        background: rowInfo.age > 20 ? 'green' : 'red'
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: It works just for initial rendering. I need to re-render the row depending on the state of the wrapping component (class).

Comment: Once you change *data* property of  `<ReactTable />` component, then your rows will be updated too. Make sure you're updating the data. Also if you create a JSFiddle that visualizes the problem - we may resolve it faster ;)

Comment: What do you mean by updating the data? I got the data for the table from DB, and I actually want to highlight rows to be deleted before actual deletion action (actual data update).
Don't know how to add react-table library to JSFiddle...

Comment: **data** property is passed to the component: `<ReactTable data={[]}/>`. Once you update the property, your component will be updated/rerendered too.

Comment: If your initial data is `this.state.data = [{id: 1, name: 'John', selected: false}, {id: 2, name: 'Doe', selected: false}]` and once you update the state, then your component will be rerendered too: `this.setState ({data: [{id: 1, name: 'John', selected: true}, {id: 2, name: 'Doe, selected: true'}]})`. So in **getTrProps** you can set the color, according **selected** value. In the same fashion as my answer's example.

Comment: Still don't understand your hints because I already pass so to say 'right' data as a property and this `<ReactTable data={[]}/>` would give me an empty table.. no?

Anyway, thanks man. The react-table author just published v. 5.0.2 which contains fixes to get a solution to the issued problem.

Comment: Concerning the data in the state – I don't write it there, I pass it right to the table by the data prop.

Comment: Yeah. I guess you include `<ReactTable />` in your own wrapper component, right? So your wrapper component has its own state. Therefore store your DB records in the wrapper component state and pass down the state to `<ReactTable data={this.state.data} />`.

Comment: It may work, but it isn't necessary =) Data is ok in props. Thanks again =)

Answer (score 2):

Fixes to the react-table 5.0.2 allow to have access to the table's instance, and the problem can be solved by calling .forceUpdate() method on the table's instance. changing_state_func in this case may look like this:

```
changing_state_func = (state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {
  if (!rowInfo) return {}
  return {
    style: {
      background: (this.state.rowsIdsArray.includes(rowInfo.row.id)) ? 'green' : null
    },
    onClick: () => {
      this.setState({rowsIdsArray: this.state.rowsIdsArray.concat([rowInfo.row.id])});
      instance.forceUpdate()
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks to the [Tanner Linsley](https://github.com/tannerlinsley) for responsiveness and quick fixes.